# In doxygen, what is the difference between ///< & ///?

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I am documenting my code in doxygen and found that there is a list of doxygen tags and two of them are:
1- ///<

2- ///

What is the difference between these tags?

I tried to Google for it but Google ignores these tags on its search!!

Comment: http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/docblocks.html#specialblock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
///<
```

This is used when you want to do single-lined comments AFTER an object.

```
///
```

This is used for single lined comments BEFORE an object